# How to Log Into Website Using Python Script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found the following code sample online:

```
# Use R to login to web site
import cookielib
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/Login'
values = {'email-email' : 'email@gmail.com',
          'password-password' : 'my_password' }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()

opener = urllib2.build_opener(
    urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
    urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
    urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
    urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies))

response = opener.open(url, data)
the_page = response.read()
http_headers = response.info()
```

I entered my actual login creds and got an error that read:

```
Warning in install.packages : package ‘urllib2’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)

Warning in install.packages : package ‘cookielib’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)
```

I am using Python 3.6.1.

Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Are you aware that R and Python are different languages?

Comment: Good. Python3 shouldn't have urllib2. It has urllib.